# LocalStorage not passing to standalone web app

Tags: javascript, ios, html, local-storage, offline-caching

I just need to hold onto some simple data in an iOS standalone web app (using `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` etc). The data is defined when the user visits the site, and saved to `localStorage.name` etc. That same page is "saved to Home Screen" but when I get there, outputting `localStorage.name` etc returns `undefined`.

I go back to Safari and it still knows the information. I pull it up with my laptop's Developer Console and I can still get all the data. It's not even a different page, let alone a different domain or anything. Everything I read tells me that `localStorage` should (with minor caveats for modifying that data) be shared between Safari and the standalone app. What am I missing?

Here's the gist of the code:

```js
if (!window.navigator.standalone) {
    // show Safari content
    if (localStorage.name != void 0 && localStorage.var2 != void 0) {
        // show normal, "add this to your home screen" language -
        // this screen shows properly
    } else {
        // show "We weren't passed our variables" language
    }
} else {
    // Show standalone/offline content
    if (localStorage.name != void 0 && localStorage.var2 != void 0) {
        // Show normal standalone app content using localStorage variables.
        // I'm not seeing this.
    } else {
        // Show "error" text, which is what I'm getting
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('container'));
        var helper = document.createElement('section')
            helper.id="helper"
        helper.innerHTML = '<h1>Sorry</h1>'
          +   '<p>There seems to be a problem with the app.</p>'
          +   '<pre>'
          +   "  Name: " + localStorage.name + "\n"
          +   "  var2: " + localStorage.var21 + "\n"
          +   '</pre>';
        document.body.insertBefore(helper,document.body.firstChild)
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, I'm in iOS 6.1. So it shouldn't be an "old" problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you haven't seen it already, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12123291/1947535) may be relevant. Specifically the fact that Safari's localStorage writes to disk are asynchronous.

Comment: I actually had but I hadn't seen a comment beneath that unfortunately tells me all I need to know…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comment: [iOS 'Web App' has different localStorage than Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545149/ios-web-app-has-different-localstorage-than-mobile-safari/12123291#comment17056733_12123291)

…has the answer. The local storage is now entirely separate from Safari to the native app.

Comment: Which is how it should be for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the localStorage reference to a key with the dot notation.  However localStorage.setItem("key", value) and localStorage.getItem("key") methods works.